# Java - creating a session

Tags: java, session

I am trying to create a session for my desktop application to store user information (as to who is currently logged in on the computer) and I want to use HttpSession for it.

I've tried reading a bit about it and I've seen answers where people do `HttpSession session = request.getSession();`, however, it says for me that it can't resolve symbol "request".

I must be doing something wrong, but I just can't seem to find what it is. Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: Do you have an object named request?

Comment: @Steven Lowes I'm not sure, I haven't heard anything like this before so probably not. I'm really new to this topic.

Comment: Unless you're building a server application, you're barking up the wrong tree. What kind of session do you need? What user info are you looking to store?

Comment: HttpSession is for use with an application server. As you are writing a desktop application this makes no sense to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpSession` is used when dealing with a Web Server. It allows you to track session state across multiple HTTP requests to the server.

In your case, you're working on a Desktop application rather than a server application. You don't need to worry about storing things in a session because your Desktop application can maintain its own state.

Comment: I do use MySQL DB but I suppose that's not really the same as working with a web server right?

Comment: @HonzaŠtefánik - Correct.

Comment: What I could use instead to save the information about the logged in user?

Comment: @HonzaŠtefánik - There are a ton of options out there and without more details about your application, the technologies you're using, and the structures you've already implemented...it's impossible to narrow down.

Comment: @JustinnNiessner It's basically a "quiz" application. I have 2 types of users, teachers and students. Teachers can create quizes (just a question with 4 choices) and students can later try to solve them. I want to save the results of students in the DB later so I want to keep the info about the students so I can later save it into DB properly. I don't think I need it for teachers.

Answer (score -1):

You have to put that statement in an if statement:

Take a look at this link - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19857-01/819-6518/gcxvp/index.html

First you have to decide if you want to use a POST or GET method for HTTP session. Then, write your code in that method.

Comment: I am assuming that you're going to be using a Servlet.

Comment: The OP already stated that this is a desktop application rather than a web application.

Comment: Check out this [link] (www.journaldev.com/1907/java-session-management-servlet-httpsession-url-rewriting+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca) and it has the different solutions to your problem.